# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

I am making a constructor for UCSDStudent, and I found my constructor has no problems.
Please point out some specific problems and help me to make my own resolution!

```
    class UCSDStudent extends Base {
    private String name;
    private long Studentnum;

    public UCSDStudent (String name, long number) {
        UCSDStudent s = new UCSDStudent();
        s.setName(name);
        s.setStudentNum(number);
    }

    public void setName(String setName) {
        name = setName;
    }
    public void setStudentNum(long setStudentNum){
        Studentnum = setStudentNum;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    public long getStudentNum () {
        return this.Studentnum;
    }

    ....... // some more code, but I will put the instantiation in the main func.

    // create Student and place in symbol table
    if(!symtab.insert (
    new UCSDStudent (buffer, number), 1)){
    System.out.println("Couldn't insert " + "student!!!"); 
    }

    ......

    UCSDStudent stu = new UCSDStudent (buffer, 0);
```

This is Base class.

```
public abstract class Base {

    public String getName () {              // identifier function

            return null;
    }               
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual stack trace from your error?

Comment: Are we supposed to tell you the problems? Isn't it usually the other way around?

Comment: Well the problem is that somewhere you are calling a function that asks for different number of arguments than you are providing. But since this code doesn't show anything interesting, there is no full error message enclosed, etc. We really cannot help you.

Comment: Wait, is this `UCSDStudent s = new UCSDStudent();` the problem? That constructor definitely isn't defined in given code.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
public UCSDStudent (String name, long number) {
        UCSDStudent s = new UCSDStudent();
        s.setName(name);
        s.setStudentNum(number);
}
```

should be changed to

```
public UCSDStudent(String name, long number) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setStudentNum(number);
}
```

There is no reason to create a new `UCSDStudent` object inside the class constructor. It will actually be lost after the constructor is executed and the values passed to the constructor will never be saved.

Also, you should take into account the `Base` superclass. If it needs any initialization, you should call its constructor from the first line of the `UCSDStudent` constructor.

Comment: You are welcome. Since the Base class does not have a constructor that requires parameters, the code is fine as it is. Otherwise, you would have had to put a call to super(...) with whatever parameters in the place of ..., at the very first line of the UCSDStudent constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public UCSDStudent (String name, long number)
{
    UCSDStudent s = new UCSDStudent();
    s.setName(name);
    s.setStudentNum(number);
}
```

This code cannot possibly compile since you are calling the default constructor of UCSDStudent, which you haven't defined. You must define a default constructor if you define a constructor that takes parameters.

Comment: It should compile, since the default constructor is defined "by default", unless there are parameters to be set (e.g., final values) in the superclass (Base), which in this instance does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @PNS: if a constructor with parameters is defined then there is no default constructor.